# How to prove that the exp: $ \mathfrak{su(n)} \to SU(n)$ is surjective

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, differential-geometry, unitary-matrices

Considering this post: [Show the exponential map $\mathfrak{u}(n)\rightarrow U(n)$ is surjective](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2275591/show-the-exponential-map-mathfrakun-rightarrow-un-is-surjective) I was trying to prove that the exponential map $ \mathfrak{su(n)} \longrightarrow SU(n)$ is surjective, where:

$$ \mathfrak{su(n)}:=  \{ A \in U(n) \space | \space Tr(A)=0 \space \} $$

$$ SU(n) := \{ A \in U(n)  \space | \det(A)=1  \}$$

but I dont know where to start, I thought about restricting the eigenvalues of a matrix, analogous to the $D_X$ in the post but can quite get it. How can we do this?

Comment: The same method works in your case. Note that $e^{i\theta_1}\cdots e^{i\theta_n}=1$ implies $\theta_1 + \cdots + \theta_n = 2N\pi$ is an integer. Then $\theta_1 + \cdots \theta_{n-1} + (\theta_n - 2N\pi) = 0$.

Comment: But I must impose that the sum of all those $ \theta_n$ to be zero in order to guarantee that the trace of  $D_X$  is zero and then use the properties of the trace to prove that $X$ is also a traceless matrix. How do I prove that the $N$ you wrote must be zero?

Comment: No. I change the last angle to $\theta_n - 2N\pi$.

Comment: Ahhh okay, since its a $2 \pi$ rotation the eigenvalue on the exponential will be the same. Thank you